# jquery Bootstrap form Validation is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqbootstrapvalidation

i am unable to use jqBootstrapValidation for my form validation. my code snippet is as follows. i have added form-group and controls class to my each field but it still not working

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(function() {
 $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation();
 });
</script>
```